# SWI-Prolog access element in nested list

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

my problem is probably really simple to solve but I'm unexperienced Prolog programmer. What I try to do is a DCG that is able to accept a bit complicated chains of values.

```
output(S) --> type(T), some(So), other(O), things(Th), strings(Sr) 
             {concat_atom(["A word ", T, So, O, Th, Sr], S)}.

strings(C) --> chars(C).

string_or_empty(C) --> "", {concat_atom([], C)}.

string_or_empty(C) --> string(C).

chars(C)           --> char(C1), chars(Rest), {concat_atom([C1, Rest], C)}.

chars(C)           --> char(C).

char(C)            --> [C1], {code_type(C1, alnum), atom_codes(C, [C1])}.

alpha_char(C)      --> [C], {code_type(C, alpha)}.
```

When I call `strings` like this `strings(S, ['a', 'b', 'c'], []).` I get expected result which is `S = abc.`

However when I call `output(S, ["type", "smth", "ot", "th", ['a', 'b', 'c']], []).` I get "false". The reason it works like that is it tries to check if whole list of letters is a character.

> Call: (12) code_type([a, b, c], alnum) ? creep
>   ERROR: Type error: 'character' expected, found '[a,b,c]' (a list)

How can I escape this?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is complete? If I ask your example query `strings(S, ['a', 'b', 'c'], []).` I get a false.

Comment: I might forgot about something, I'll update my post ASAP.